# Calling indexed components dynamically in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular6

I have created different layouts of my app in different component and I am accessing it using *ngIf condition like this

```
<app-layout1 *ngIf="selected==1"></app-layout1>
<app-layout2 *ngIf="selected==2"></app-layout2>
<app-layout3 *ngIf="selected==3"></app-layout3>
```

I was wondering If we have any more efficient way of doing same like:

```
<app-layout[selected]></app-layout[selected]>
```

Comment: No , You have to give component manually IMO

Answer (score 0):

No , You have to write components manually...

There is no shortcut to that!